# Which jar file should I import for OracleConnection?

Tags: java

I am calling an `enqueue()` and `dequeue()` method on Connection instance and getting this error:

```
XMLQueue.java:58: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol : method enqueue(java.lang.String,oracle.jdbc.aq.AQEnqueueOptions,oracle.jdbc.aq.AQMessage)
[javac] location: class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection
[javac] aConnection.getNativeConnection().enqueue(
[javac] ^
```

So which jar files should i import?

Comment: You should import oracle JDBC driver available at oracle website. It's possible you have wrong version of it.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you dealing with?

Comment: Well I m using ojdbc14.jar and it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think ojdbc6.jar will solve your problem, its available on oracle website.

Answer (score 0):

Download the [ojdbc6 jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadojdbc6jar.htm) for this. If you search for the classes available in that jar, you can find that it contains the `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection.class` which is missing for you.

Comment: @suvendu - That will work. Are you sure the jar is present in your classpath?!